# Failed to start of service MongoDB community4.2 using Homebrew in Mac OS Mojave 10.14

Tags: mongodb, permissions, installation, mongodb-4.2

Error message while starting the mongoDB service. 
Error:

> Permission denied @ rb_sysopen -
>   /Users/syedahmed/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist

I installed/reinstall the mongoDB couple times. 
But I am getting same problem

> " error : permission denied"

I am using the community@4.2 edition in Mac OS Mojave 10.14

I have tried different ways after reading suggestions in stack overflow but nothing has worked.

I have installed following [the instruction from mongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/).

The services doesn't start.

how to config the username and password using config?  I am not sure.

while installing from brew it did not ask for config any password or username.

brew services start mongodb-community@4.2

if I start service typing just:  mongo
Following error message comes:

> MongoDB shell version v4.2.0 connecting to:
>   mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
>   2019-09-01T23:23:31.392-0400 E QUERY [js] Error: couldn't connect to
>   server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException:
>   Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused
>   : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17 @(connect):2:6
>   2019-09-01T23:23:31.397-0400 F - [main] exception: connect failed
>   2019-09-01T23:23:31.397-0400 E - [main] exiting with code 1 –

Comment: Have you noticed the  **Permission denied** in the error messages?

Comment: is this port number available: `Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused`

Comment: I am using the MacOS Mojave 10.14.5.  I have installed using the brew. It goes to default folder. Even if you try with other version it also doesn't allow to access.

Answer (score 2):

use code below before `mongo`

```
sudo brew services start mongodb-community
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is here:

1. Make a directory as - sudo mkdir -p /data/db
2. That will make a directory named as db and than try to start with commands - sudo mongod

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and it could be due to your service not being able to create  the socket (check with `netstat -an | grep 27017` if  you have it up properly)

What I did:

Create a properly placed `data/db` on `System/Volumes/Data/data/db`, with

```sh
sudo mkdir -p /System/Volumes/Data/data/db
sudo chown -R `id -un` /System/Volumes/Data/data/db
```

And, then, add that path to `mongod.conf` (located on `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`), replacing `dbPath` there:

```
...
storage:
  dbPath: /System/Volumes/Data/data/db
...
```

Then, restart it. If you are using brew, do:

```sh
brew services restart mongodb-community
```

Source: https://zellwk.com/blog/install-mongodb/